# How to fix music overlapping in xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am making a music app. I manually make a table view by making a 2 viewcontroller, instead of tab bar view controller.

The problem is, If I click a table cell, the music will play. But If I press back then click again another cell, a new song will play and the current song that is playing wont stop. I want to stop the current playing song as soon as I click a new cell so that the songs wont overlap.

I also added pictures for clearer understanding. Hope you can help. Thank you.

This is the code from my ViewController1

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return songtitle.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.mytbl.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for:     indexPath) as! tableviewcell

    cell.songphoto.image = UIImage(named: img[indexPath.row])
    cell.titledisplay.text = songtitle[indexPath.row]    

    return cell    
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {        
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "go2", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {    
    let myconn = segue.destination as! vc2    
    let indexPath = mytbl.indexPathForSelectedRow

    //This is the logic I made but it is not working

    if myconn.audioplayer.isPlaying == false{        
        myconn.selectedsong = (indexPath?.row)!
    }  else {
        myconn.audioplayer.stop()
        myconn.selectedsong = (indexPath?.row)!
    }
}
```

I made the logic up there inside my prepare segue but it is not working.
[This is my viewcontroller that has cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ItIm.jpg)
This is the code from my ViewController2

```
var audioplayer = AVAudioPlayer()    
var selectedsong = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()    

    titlearea.text = songtitle[selectedsong]    
    songpic.image = UIImage(named: img[selectedsong])    

    do {
        let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: songtitle[selectedsong], ofType: ".mp3")

        try audioplayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!) as URL)

        audioplayer.play()    

        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector:     #selector(vc2.updateProgressView), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    catch
    {    
        print("ERROR")
    }
}

@IBAction func play(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    if !audioplayer.isPlaying{
        audioplayer.play() 
    }
}
```

[This is my second Viewcontroller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eLbe.jpg)

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and reformat your code as well, in its current state its quite impossible to read.

Comment: done editing. im sorry

Comment: the only code in my back button is dismissanimation view controller code.

Comment: OK, but you keep showing code that isn't your code and you keep not showing the code we need to see, so it's impossible to understand what you're really doing. Sorry, can't help under those circumstances.

Comment: it is actually incredibly difficult to synchronize cells in a table, in iOS. to be totally honest I just wouldn't bother unless you are an experience engineer.  A simple solution is, just make a singleton somewhere (or just a static class - a global - whatever) and call to that system to play the music.  Enjoy!

Comment: note that iPhones have only 1x audio speaker.  so you should ultimately use a singleton of some type.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your segue is initializing a new instance of `vc2` (this is a terrible class name, by the way; consider naming your view controller something more descriptive) each time it's performed. The result of this is that when you call `myconn.audioplayer.stop()`, you're not sending the `stop()` method to the same audio player that's currently playing, but rather to a brand-new one you just made.

What I'd recommend doing instead is to keep a property containing a reference to the currently-playing audio player. When you start playing, assign that player to the property, and when you want to stop, send the `stop()` method to the object pointed to by the property.